# Cannot understand why for loop giving such results in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Below is the code  I am trying to execute, where `Percentage` is a tibble which have been type-casted from a dataframe .Percentage is a one column tibble which have data as below and have class as given below

```
> class(Percentage)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Having Sample data as below

1. Closed
   2   Closed
   3   Closed
   4   Open  and so on

But each time I execute it, only `print(i)` is printed for all values of `i`. The `print(1)` is printed only once.

```
Percentage = as_tibble(Com_Data_Final$ST)
View(Percentage)

    CC = 0
    OC = 0
    
    for (i in Percentage){ 
      print(1)
      print(i)
      if(i == 'Closed'){
        CC = CC + 1 
        print(i)
      } else {
        OC = OC + 1
      }
    }
```

out put being

```
[1] 1
   [1] "Closed" "Closed" "Closed" "Open"   "Closed" "Closed" "Open"   "Closed"
   [9] "Closed" "Open"   "Closed" "Closed" "Open"   "Closed" "Closed" "Open"  
  [17] "Closed" "Closed" "Closed" "Closed" "Closed" "Closed" and other values from percentage
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Percentage)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Percentage, 20))`.

Comment: Indeed, it is important how exactly your Percentage object looks like. Probably you are iterating over other thing you want to

Comment: Should you be iterating through the column that contains your characters within your tibble, e.g. `for (i in Percentage$mycolumn)` rather than `for (i in Percentage)`?